# How can I find out the keyboard shortcut assignments in the Atom text editor?

Tags: editor, keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

How can I review the current keyboard bindings in a running instance of the [Atom text editor](https://atom.io/)

Answer (score 32):

You can find the full set of current keyboard shortcuts in the Settings View:

1. Press <kbd>Cmd+,</kbd> on OS X or <kbd>Ctrl+,</kbd> on Windows/Linux
2. Select Keybindings from the list of sections in the upper left
3. Scroll through the list to find what you want or search for it by key or command name in the search box

Another way you can find keybindings is if you want to know what a particular key does, you can open the Keybinding Resolver view:

1. Press <kbd>Cmd+.</kbd> on OS X or <kbd>Ctrl+.</kbd> on Windows/Linux
2. Press the key or key combination you're curious about and a list will show up of all commands that are mapped to that key
3. The one highlighted in a different color is the one that "wins" in whatever area of the application currently has focus (when different areas of the app have focus, some keys mean different things)

This view is also very useful for situations where you want to be sure that Atom is receiving the key combination you're pressing correctly.

The issue with the `Open Your Keymap` command is that it only shows you your personal *overrides* of the keybindings that the Atom application already has. It does nothing to tell you the full set or even if your keybindings are being used in a particular situation. That's what the above techniques are for.

Comment: Note that you'll need to restart Atom to take into accoun the changes.

Comment: This answer isn't about making changes to anything, only showing what already exists. Additionally, you shouldn't need to restart Atom to make changes to the `keymap.cson` take effect. It is designed to load them automatically.

Comment: Well, I tried using Debian and I had to restart it manually.

Comment: If you can reproduce that reliably, then please file a bug on https://github.com/atom/atom-keymap

Comment: I just experienced the same problem: I added my first keybinding to `keymap.cson` and it didn't take effect until i restarted Atom. However, subsequent updates to `keymap.cson` took effect as soon as I saved the file. I am using *Atom 1.10.0* on *Ubuntu 16.04*.